# Is there a way to conditionally index 3D-numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Having an array A with the shape `(2,6, 60)`, is it possible to index it based on a binary array B of shape `(6,)`?

The 6 and 60 is quite arbitrary, they are simply the 2D data I wish to access.

The underlying thing I am trying to do is to calculate two variants of the 2D data (in this case, `(6,60)`) and then efficiently select the ones with the lowest total sum - that is where the binary `(6,)` array comes from.

Example: For `B = [1,0,1,0,1,0]` what I wish to receive is equal to stacking

```
A[1,0,:]
A[0,1,:]
A[1,2,:]
A[0,3,:]
A[1,4,:]
A[0,5,:]
```

but I would like to do it by direct indexing and not a for-loop.

I have tried `A[B], A[:,B,:], A[B,:,:] A[:,:,B]` with none of them providing the desired (6,60) matrix.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
A = np.atleast_3d(A)
A = np.tile(A, (1,1,60)
B = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
A[B]
```

Expected results are a `(6,60)` array containing the elements from A as described above, the received is either `(2,6,60)` or `(6,6,60)`.

Thank you in advance,
Linus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a range of the indices you want to iterate over, in your case from 0 to 5:

```
count = A.shape[1]

indices = np.arange(count)  # np.arange(6) for your particular case

>>> print(indices)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

And then you can use that to do your advanced indexing:

```
result_array = A[B[indices], indices, :]
```

If you always use the full range from 0 to length - 1 (i.e. 0 to 5 in your case) of the second axis of `A` in increasing order, you can simplify that to:

```
result_array = A[B, indices, :]
# or the ugly result_array = A[B, np.arange(A.shape[1]), :]
```

Or even this if it's always 6:

```
result_array = A[B, np.arange(6), :]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using `np.take_along_axis` (from version 1.15 - [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html#numpy.take_along_axis))

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(2*6*6).reshape((2,6,6))
m = np.zeros(6, int)
m[0] = 1
#example: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

np.take_along_axis(x, m[None, :, None], 0)   #add dimensions to mask to match array dimensions

>>array([[[36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
        [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
        [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
        [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]])
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check this solution out and compare to blubberdiblub's!